# How to create proxy server for react native/ how to store keys in react native?

Tags: react-native, redux, keystore, android-keystore

Can anyone help me with storing secret keys in react native? I have read that it has threat from reverse engineering and the solution was to create proxy ? how can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

For secret keys its a problematic if you store it in AsyncStorage. But there are other ways in both android and ios where you can store it safely.

For android:

You can store it in secured shared preferences. in that way sensitive data can be kept at the client side itself. [RN- secured shared preferences](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#android---secure-shared-preferences)
You can check this document itslef. its pretty good.

FOr Ios:

You can store it in keychain services. [RN - keychain](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#ios---keychain-services). you can find some examples on how to store sensitive data in keychain. there's a lib react-native-keychain for that i believe [rn-keychain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keychain)

Do letme know in case of any doubts

Comment: can i use react-native-encrypted-storage for android?